# O emulador Android SDK é muito lento(inicialização e execução), como melhorar?

Tags: android, virtualbox, emulador

O Android SDK inclui um emulador de dispositivo móvel - um dispositivo móvel virtual que roda em seu computador. O emulador permite que você desenvolver e testar aplicativos Android sem o uso de um dispositivo físico. Esse emulador possui um desempenho baixo, ou seja, na sua inicialização e na sua performance na execução de aplicativos. Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Pedro, acho que ficaria melhor 'visualizável', se tu colocasse as duas respostas como respostas. É válido você mesmo pode responder suas perguntas.

Comment: @emanuelsn obrigado por dar essa dica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou mostrar 2 opções que você pode utilizar para sanar com esse problema ou pelo menos amenizar:
1º - Se você utiliza um computador com um processador da Intel que tenha a tecnologia Intel Virtualization, instale o pacote que dá suporte a escolha da CPU da Intel na criação do AVD. Abra o SDK Manager com o comando android e instale o pacote “Intel x86 Atom System Image” para a versão do Android que pretende usar como na figura abaixo:

[image: Intel]

E quando for criar um AVD escolher CPU “Intel Atom (x86)” como na figura abaixo:

[image: Configuração]

2º - Você ainda pode utilizar outro emulador, no caso o Genymotion que da suporte para varias versões do android, bem como emulador um modelo dispositivo reais (Motorola D1 Razr, Google Nexus, sony Xperia etc). Só entrar nesse link : [Genymotion](https://shop.genymotion.com/index.php?controller=order-opc) e baixar o instalador que vem junto com VirtualBox para realizar a emulação e utilizar o Genymotion plugin para Eclipse para executar seus aplicativos.